# Laravel 4 never load namespace

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a custom namespace in my configuration files.
Do I need to reference every class I want to use thereafter?

```
<?PHP
namespace MyCustomNamespace;
use BaseController;
use View;
use Redirect;
// [...]
?>
```

Comment: Yes, you do. that's PHP requirements.

Comment: Would there be a list of all the Laravel namespaces that we could reference all at once perhaps to simplify the process?

Comment: Unfortunately php don't support that. In java, you can do something like /app/*.

Comment: However, in Laravel you can use something /view